# Getting Error for GridSearchCV while tuning hyperparameters

Tags: scikit-learn, hyperparameters

I am getting weird error while doing hyperparameter tuning for GridSearch.
I have got some best parameters from randomizedsearchcv and i am trying to fit those parameters in grid search cv.
I am getting error

**Parameter grid for parameter (criterion) needs to be a list or numpy array, but got (<class 'str'>). Single values need to be wrapped in a list with one element.**

Below is the code

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
clf=RandomForestClassifier()
n_estimators=rf_random_tuned.best_params_['n_estimators']
criterion=rf_random_tuned.best_params_['criterion']
max_depth=rf_random_tuned.best_params_['max_depth']
min_samples_split=rf_random_tuned.best_params_['min_samples_split']
min_samples_leaf=rf_random_tuned.best_params_['min_samples_leaf']
max_features=rf_random_tuned.best_params_['max_features']
param_grid_1={'n_estimators':[n_estimators-100,n_estimators,n_estimators+100],
           'criterion':criterion,
           'max_depth':[max_depth-1,max_depth-0.5,max_depth,max_depth+0.5,max_depth+1],
           'min_samples_split':[min_samples_split-14,min_samples_split,min_samples_split+14],
           'min_samples_leaf':[min_samples_leaf-0.16,min_samples_leaf,min_samples_leaf+0.16],
           'max_features':max_features
          }
rf_grid=GridSearchCV(estimator=clf,param_grid=param_grid_1,cv=5)
rf_grid.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html):

> param_grid: dict or list of dictionaries

> Dictionary with parameters names (str) as keys ***and lists of parameter settings to try as values***, or a list of such dictionaries, in which case the grids spanned by each dictionary in the list are explored. This enables searching over any sequence of parameter settings.

Basically, it is complaining wrt keys `'criterion'` and `'max_features'`, whose values should be passed as lists.